# How to pass many to many relations to view as array[Laravel 5]

Tags: php, laravel-5

I try to pass array to view for my relations.... I have users and projects table in realation....

Here is User Model:

```
public function projects(){
    return $this ->belongsToMany('App\Project','project_user');
}


public function getUserList(){
    return $this -> projects;
}
```

Here is my home controller:

```
public function project(User $project){
            $this -> selected = $project;
            return view('projects',array('selected' =>$project -> selected -> getUserList()->lists('id') ));
        }
```

**NOTE**

If I change my home controller, this line:

```
return view('projects',array('selected' => $project -> selected -> getUserList()->lists('id') ));
```

into this:

```
return view('projects',array('selected' => Auth::user -> getUserList()->lists('id') ));
```

it works fine...

Anyone know why It now work with method injection?

Comment: First, why do you use spaces between "->"? That annoys me very much, also, why is a User object called $project? I did not understand your code, but are you trying to get all projects that are associated to a user? Or maybe all users of a project? If yes there is a much cleaner way to get it using eloquent I can show you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: Laravel doesn't know what to do when you type-hint your User model.

Longer answer: Since the current logged in user's information is stored in the Authentication portion of Laravel's code, one option is to type-hint the `Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Guard` interface ([API docs](http://laravel.com/api/5.0/Illuminate/Contracts/Auth/Guard.html)) in your method descriptor to get an instance of it.

You can then use the `user` property to access an instance of the User model reflecting the currently logged in user. This code is essentially what you already have here: `Auth::user -> getUserList()->lists('id')`.

The benefit to using the `Guard` interface inside of `Illuminate\Contracts` is that if a package or service provider redefines the concrete implementation of the  `Guard` interface (the reason to do this would be swapping out *how* authentication works in your application), your code will not require changes due to it being bound to the contract defined by that interface, rather than using the `Auth` facade which may no longer function in the same manner.

Hope this helps! Feel free to ask questions :)